# How works with a HashMap in frontend with Jhipster?

Tags: java, html, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I am developing a Jhipster app in which I have a Entity with a `Map<String, String>`, in backend all works fine. But I don't know what do to show the map in the entity detail view since jhipster does not generate it to me and I have to do it manually.

Im starting with angular and I dont know how to declare a map in the `entity.model.ts` or how can I iterate in the html.

> Entity.java

```
....Other attributes....

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="key")
    @Column(name="value")
    @CollectionTable(name="map", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="entity_id"))
    private Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<>();

....getters and setters....
```

> entity.model.ts

```
export class entity implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
    ) {
    }
}
```

> entity-view.component.html

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Key</span></th>
                <th><span>Value</span></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let map of entity.map">
                <td><span>{{map.key}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{map.value}}</span></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post your `.Entity.json` file? it should be inside the `.hjipster` folder in your project's root folder

Comment: Have you found a solution?